# stop a program when other program is running in a loop

Tags: python, linux, shell, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

this is what i am trying to do in linux (raspberry pi 4).. **when the pi 4 boots, run a video in chromium-browser in kiosk... at the same time run a python3 script in background** (the bold part is done by making changes in /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart)  the python script which I am trying to run will have a video in it... now i want to *stop or pause the chromium-browser's video, play the script's video on foreground in full screen and as soon as the video is over, play the chromium-browser's video in full screen again* ... I am stuck at this part(the italic part)

Comment: Without both communicating together, you can't. Just open 2 threads each running a `subprocess` command. Whenever one encounters an error assign a global variable to False. And in the main thread if the global is False, kill the threads. Your main loop would be watching `while variable == True`.

Comment: hey thanks for the reply, i was wondering if it's possible to do it using a script where in a while loop, i fetch the pid of chromium-browser and say a video player omxplayer, when the omxplayer starts playing, kill the chromium-browser and when it(omxplayer) stops, start the chromium browser... is it possible, sorry it's just a guess :(

Comment: That is possible but you need a library to do that. Find a library to get you a PID and a state.

Comment: what's easier? btw you mentioned "whenever one encounters an error..." can closing of the video player when the video is over considered as an error?

Comment: An error is whatever you want it to be. A lazy method I do is usually throw a "Success" error like so: `class SuccessException(Exception): pass` then I use it `if success: raise SuccessException("Success!")` and I wrap it all in a `try` and `except` block.

Comment: Hard to say without knowing more about your actual python script and understanding what initiates the switch between the two and how often they loop.  Can you share your python script and how often the python script runs, how over the video runs, what initiates the change between the two, etc.?